# mysql connector doesn't connect to my xxamp localhost

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am using netbeans 8.2 with xxamp. mysql `connector.jar` is 8.0.18.
It doesn't show any errors but whenever I press the button, the value from jUsername isn't inserted and instead the exception in the catch is shown. Please help.

```java
private void StartButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

  try {
    String query = "INSERT INTO 'score' ('Name') VALUES (?)";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/userscore", "root", "");
    pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
    pst.setString(1, jUsername.getText());
    DifficultyPanel dpanel =new DifficultyPanel();
    dpanel.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Your Username To Continue");
  }
}
```

Comment: Call the `e.printStackTrace()` method of the catched exception. It will show you the reason.

Comment: i tried e.printStackTrack() and figured out its something with the time zone. ``` ?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC ```. now it doesnt show any errors but the value is still not added into the db